# Is it possible to automatically add class to caps in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, font-size

I got a web design with titles in small caps. I'd like to set manually the size of small caps, because my font seems not to support font variants.

Here is my web design example :
[Web design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFXlu.png)

Here is the CSS result with "font-variant" property :
[CSS example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qZf5.png)

Then, I had the idea to select the big caps in CSS/jQuery to manually set their sizes. Is it possible ?

Thank you,
Regards

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  The ask process also guides you on how to formulate a question so that it doesn't get downvoted or closed.

Comment: Please provide your code as well and refer to the link that freedomn provided above